# can you prevent Wifi from shutting off during screen lock or screen lock?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an app that creates time lapse movies on os x from webcams available through a url. Recently I have had lots of users complaining that the recordings are dropping tons of frames. I have isolated the problem to Yosemite disconnecting the wifi when the screen locks. Is there a way to let the system know that it is important that your app keeps the network connection? It is annoying to tell the users to go in and disable screen locking just to use my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Wi-Fi is really turning off, [that sounds like an Apple bug](http://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/1wx2r9/wifi_disconnects_after_putting_display_to_sleep/).

You can disable [App Nap](https://www.apple.com/osx/advanced-technologies/) & idle sleep by [registering an "activity"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000316-SW34).

The `NSActivityUserInitiated` option should be enough.

There's also `NSActivityIdleDisplaySleepDisabled`.