# How to detect whether macOS is configured to sleep

Tags: macos

I have application that needs to be available at all times and I what to warn the user if the macOS computer is configured to sleep (not turn off the display or hard disk because that's ok).

The Energy Saver screen and the terminology has changed so there might be different implementation depending on macOS version. On High Sierra it's called "Computer sleep" and it can be set to some minutes/hours or 'Never'. On Mojave there's a checkbox called "Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off" and a slider for the "Turn display off after:" that can be set to some minutes/hours or 'Never' (it's not possible to set computer sleep and display sleep individually).

I'm aware of how to monitor sleep states and that is not what I want. And I don't want to prevent the computer from sleeping if that is what the user really wants - I just want to warn the user if sleep is set to something else than 'Never'.

The console command "pmset -g" does return the answer so one option could be to parse that - but I would prefer an API that I could just call.

Comment: Are you going to warn them on closing the computer screen?  I think it's too late at that point.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Related: [can you prevent Wifi from shutting off during screen lock or screen lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488037/can-you-prevent-wifi-from-shutting-off-during-screen-lock-or-screen-lock/31488751#31488751).

Comment: @zero298: No, not when closing the computer lid. I'm talking about the situation when the computer is configured to sleep after e.g. 15 minutes.